# how to get cliend id and access token in instagram api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

how to get client id and access token in instagram api? 
i'm go to http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ for get cliend id but after i sign up my app, i don't get client id? how to get client id and access token in instagram api?
i'm follow this tutorial : http://blog.ajmalafif.com/instagram-gem-with-rails/
please help me, thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client id is generated by instagram when you register you application on page http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

Access token is generated when user authorizes using your app